# (libgdx/java) ArrayList won't clear/delete instance of class?

Tags: arraylist, timer, libgdx

**Item class:**

```
       public class Item {
          public float x, y, speedx, speedy;
        public Rectangle container;
        public Texture texture;
       static Timer timer = new Timer();
      static  int amount;
       static int spawned;
        public int itemtype;
        //   float delay = 1; // seconds

        public void move() {
            x += speedx;
            y += speedy;

            container.x = x;
            container.y = y;

        }
  public void setTexture(int itemtype){
        switch(itemtype){
            case 1:
                texture = new Texture("items/item1.png");
                break;
            case 2:
                texture = new Texture("items/item2.png");
                break;
            case 3:
                texture = new Texture("items/item3.png");
                break;
            case 4:
                texture = new Texture("items/item4.png");
                break;
            case 5:
                texture = new Texture("items/item5.png");
                break;
            case 6:
                texture = new Texture("items/item6.png");
                break;
            case 7:
                texture = new Texture("items/item7.png");
                break;
            case 8:
                texture = new Texture("items/item8.png");
                break;
            case 9:
                texture = new Texture("items/item9.png");
                break;
            case 10:
                texture = new Texture("items/item10.png");
                break;
            default:
                texture = new Texture("items/error.png");
                break;
        }

    }
          public static void spawnItem(int amount){
            Item.amount = amount;
              mainscreen.items.clear();
                  //  for(int spawned = 0; spawned <= amount; spawned++){



                        timer.schedule(new Timer.Task() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                if (mainscreen.canclick == false) {
                                    Item item = new Item();
                                    item.x = 600;
                                    item.y = -42;
                                    item.speedx = -20;
                                    item.speedy = 0;
                                    Rectangle itemcontainer = new Rectangle();
                                    itemcontainer.x = item.x;
                                    itemcontainer.y = item.y;
                                    itemcontainer.width =                       mainscreen.container.getWidth() / 4f;
                                    itemcontainer.height = mainscreen.container.getHeight() - 15f;
                                    item.container = itemcontainer;
         item.itemtype = MathUtils.random(1, 10);
item.setTexture(item.itemtype);
                                    mainscreen.items.add(item);
                                    spawned++;
                                }
                                for (Item item : mainscreen.items) {
                                    if (item.x <= -4000) {
                                        if (spawned >= Item.amount) {
                                            mainscreen.canclick = true;


                                            timer.stop();
                                            spawned = 0;
                                        }

                                    } else {

                                    }
                                }
                           }
                        }, 0, 0.325f);

                }
    public void dispose(){
        texture.dispose();
    }
            }
```

**Mainscreen class:**

```
public class mainscreen implements Screen, GestureDetector.GestureListener,InputProcessor {
    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        this.delta = delta;
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(115 / 255F, 115 / 255F, 115 / 255F, 1 / 255F);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

      if(Gdx.input.justTouched()) {

          Vector3 touch1 = new Vector3(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0);
          camera.unproject(touch1);


          if (debug.contains(touch1.x, touch1.y)) {
              items.clear();
          }

          if (start.contains(touch1.x, touch1.y)) {
          if (canclick == true) {

                  canclick = false;

    Item.spawnItem(20);
              }

          }
      }

}
```

**LOG:**
On first click start:
(After the Timer has finished)

```
canclick: true
items list: [com.abc.luckyllama.Item@37237aa0, com.abc.luckyllama.Item@2de938e3, com.abc.luckyllama.Item@3cb912d5, com.abc.luckyllama.Item@2bae592c, com.abc.luckyllama.Item@774c083, com.abc.luckyllama.Item@633edeae, com.abc.luckyllama.Item@176557a6, com.abc.luckyllama.Item@4edb1b5f, com.abc.luckyllama.Item@6f8abadf, com.abc.luckyllama.Item@7a54d22e, com.abc.luckyllama.Item@473162a5, com.abc.luckyllama.Item@51a698ff, com.abc.luckyllama.Item@6bc08c56, com.abc.luckyllama.Item@37d9e6a2, com.abc.luckyllama.Item@7bb19eb6, com.abc.luckyllama.Item@1eb5805f, com.abc.luckyllama.Item@71780de3, com.abc.luckyllama.Item@9ec0998, com.abc.luckyllama.Item@7edf723d, com.abc.luckyllama.Item@4c5aa2c1]
```

After clicking the debug button(clears arraylist):

```
canclick: true
items list: []
```

After clicking the start button again:
(After the Timer has finished)

```
 canclick: true
items list: [com.abc.luckyllama.Item@7d7cb9bc, com.abc.luckyllama.Item@1435cf42, com.abc.luckyllama.Item@117e1963, com.abc.luckyllama.Item@82bfd27, com.abc.luckyllama.Item@108214c7, com.abc.luckyllama.Item@2a77864a, com.abc.luckyllama.Item@4b232766, com.abc.luckyllama.Item@1cb629e0, com.abc.luckyllama.Item@1c92229d, com.abc.luckyllama.Item@ac1b293, com.abc.luckyllama.Item@588bbcba, com.abc.luckyllama.Item@75df6762, com.abc.luckyllama.Item@78d4358e, com.abc.luckyllama.Item@7f86452d, com.abc.luckyllama.Item@7aed480b, com.abc.luckyllama.Item@7407d443, com.abc.luckyllama.Item@2da6e708, com.abc.luckyllama.Item@604470bc, com.abc.luckyllama.Item@70f9d1af, com.abc.luckyllama.Item@3a16a63f, com.abc.luckyllama.Item@201288d2, com.abc.luckyllama.Item@6310ddfc, com.abc.luckyllama.Item@5d5a1c98, com.abc.luckyllama.Item@52727e52, com.abc.luckyllama.Item@669228d6]
```

You see that the Items inside the ArrayList didn't get cleared. It increased. I think that's because the instances of Item created in spawnItem() are still there. How do I fix this?

I noticed that every time I click the button there aren't more items. The items are spawned faster. But how to stop this?

Comment: I think some of your critical code is missing above. No where above do you add anything to the list without immediately removing it. By the way, you are leaking copies of the same Texture by using `new Texture(...)` and not retaining the reference for later disposal.

Comment: Sorry I added this by mistake(when removing it the problem is still there)

Comment: There are different object in your lists, so it is not appending objects. It is not impossible to not clear objects when you call "clear" method. Probably your click action works multiple times.

Comment: I noticed that every time I click the button the items are spawned faster. (is timer is stopping faster?) But how to stop this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it! The problem was that I needed to create a Timer.Task seperately and the use `task.cancel();` to **stop the Timer.Task**:

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Timer;
public class Item {
public static Timer.Task task;
   public static void spawnItem(int amount){
        Item.amount = amount;

        task = new Timer.Task() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                if (mainscreen.canclick == false) {
                    item = new Item();

                    item.x = 600;
                    item.y = -42;
                    item.speedx = -20;
                    item.speedy = 0;
                    Rectangle itemcontainer = new Rectangle();
                    itemcontainer.x = item.x;
                    itemcontainer.y = item.y;
                    itemcontainer.width = mainscreen.container.getWidth() / 3f;
                    itemcontainer.height = mainscreen.container.getHeight() - 15f;
                    item.container = itemcontainer;
                    item.itemtype = MathUtils.random(1, 10);

                    item.setTexture(item.itemtype);


                    mainscreen.items.add(item);
                    mainscreen.itemsspawned += 1;


                    //   mainscreen.items.remove(item);


                    spawned++;
                }
                for (Item item : mainscreen.items) {
                    if (item.x <= -4000) {
                        if (spawned >= Item.amount) {
                            mainscreen.canclick = true;

                            timer.clear();
                            timer.stop();
                            task.cancel();
                            spawned = 0;

                        }

                    }
                }


            }
        };


        timer.schedule(task, 0, 0.4f);

    }
}
```